# Changing indentation settings in the Spyder editor for Python

Tags: python, indentation, spyder

I am using the Spyder editor for Python.
I need to change the indentation setting (e.g., let "tab" mean "4 spaces").

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Spyder v. 4.0 or higher:

> Tools >>> Preferences >>> Editor >>> Source code >>> Indentation
>   characters

Other versions:

> Tools >>> Preferences >>> Editor >>> Advanced settings >>> Indentation
>   characters

Comment: That's great! Had to set "indentation characters" to "4 spaces" and then check "tab always indent" to get the desired effect I was looking for

Comment: The tab width seems very large. It goes beyond `class` all the way to flush up against the class name. Is there any way to shrink the indentation width? I prefer mine to be equivalent to 2 spaces.

Comment: Oh wait I got it. That's unusual though --rather than spaces, the tab width is determined by pixels. Kind of cool though I guess. Anyway, at the default font size 15 pixels should emulate a two space tab width.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac w/ Spyder 4.0.1, it's

**Python -> Preference -> Editor -> Source Code (tab) -> Indentation characters**

Answer (score 0):

go to >>>Tools in the menu bar

Preferences >>> Editor >>> Advanced settings >>> Indentation characters

set indentation characters: to "4 spaces"

hurray! Mission accomplished

Comment: What's the difference from [this existed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36188174/5376789)?