# How to prevent tab characters from being converted to spaces in console output when using IPython in Spyder

Tags: python, excel, ipython, spyder, copy-paste

In IDLE Python if I do `print "a\tb"`  I get an output that looks like: `a[TAB]b`.

If I do the same in IPython in Spyder, then I get an output that looks like: `a[7 spaces]b`

I like to output tables of data as tab delimited text to make it easier to copy from the console and paste it to Excel. If the tabs get converted to spaces it becomes more difficult.

Is there any setting within IPython or Spyder which controls how TAB characters are displayed? I am using Spyder+IPython on a Windows 10 desktop. I realized I could just write the data to a file, but in this case it is more convenient to just use the console and the clipboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing indentation settings in the Spyder editor for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187784/changing-indentation-settings-in-the-spyder-editor-for-python)

Comment: the setting discussed in that post appears to control the formatting in the code editor.  I want to adjust the formatting in the console output.

Comment: Did you find out of it yet? it is allowed to answer own questions.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to get it to do what I want with the ipython console in spyder.  But spyder also has a normal python console and that console maintains the tab characters. So in cases where I don't need the ipython extensions it works for me to use the python console.

Comment: @ivan7707 - I don't think this is a duplicate to the question you linked.

Comment: @amel spyder does no longer include the python console. (as of e.g. 3.3.1)

Comment: There is now work done in the corresponding issue https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/396 .

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) For the record, this problem was solved in our **4.1.0** version, released in March 2020.