# How to add python console in spyder

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder

After upgrade spyder version 3.2.1 .I con't find the python console in spyder.
It is inconvenient when i plot data interactively though the Ipython console.How can i add the python console to the spyder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) The Python console was completely removed in Spyder **3.2.0** and it's not coming back. For the reasons to do that, please read this [Github issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4524).

If you want to create interactive plots in the IPython console, you need to change your graphics backend to *Automatic* in

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics Backend`

Comment: In my case I also had to restart Spyder afterwards ;)

Comment: @hipoglucido, you only need to restart the kernel. There's no need to restart Spyder completely.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba - When I do this, the plots are no longer blocking. Is there a way to make the plots blocking when plt.show() is called?

Comment: Uncheck the option called `Activate support` in `Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`

Comment: It also gives problem when changing matplotlib backend: ```/home/joao/untitled3.py:4: UserWarning: 
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

The backend was *originally* set to 'Qt5Agg' by the following code:
  File "/home/joao/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 268, in <module>
    main()```

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes, your backend was set somewhere else and so Spyder can't set it for you. Look for `matplotlibrc` files in your system.

Answer (score 5):

The variable explorer in makes Spyder great for debugging but it doesn't stack up to full featured IDE's such as PyCharm community edition. In my opinion, Spyder is a much worse debugger since the console was removed so after 2 months of frustration with the newer version I "downgraded" back to version 3.1.4 which I love.

This will get you back to the version of Spyder where the beloved console still exists:

conda uninstall spyder

conda install spyder=3.1.4

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's exactly the thing you find lacking from our debugger with the IPython console? We worked hard to port almost all features from the old Python to the IPython one.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, I will try and make a youtube video that demonstrates how I use the console in Spyder. The sort version is "what does the ipython console add if you are developing a command line script?".

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking the extra time to do that. It'd be really good for us.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba see this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980943/how-to-prevent-tab-characters-being-converted-to-spaces-in-console-output-when-u ipython replaced tabs with spaces during print, which is at least for me undesired in some circumstances.

Comment: @Joma, we don't have control over that, but I think it's necessary to avoid mixing spaces and tabs when writing code in the console

Comment: I think so, the debugger is hard to use in my current spyder version, hopefully there may be some good implementation related to this

Answer (score 1):

Alt + Z or

View -> Panes -> Ipython Console