# Is pressing *enter* in Spyder (in Python) a tab or 4 spaces?

Tags: python, tabs, spyder, spaces, enter

I have read all about the horrendous nature of tabs instead of spaces in Python. When I press *enter* in Spyder, is the IDE adding a tab or 4 spaces?

Comment: Spyder should use the indentation method you set up in `Tools > Preferences > Editor > Advanced settings > Indentation characters`. Easiest way to find out yourself is to create a file with tabs, spaces and enters, then open it in a HEX editor, i.e. [this online editor](https://hexed.it/?hl=de). If you see HEX value `09`, a tab was used, in case of several `20`s, spaces were added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing indentation settings in the Spyder editor for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187784/changing-indentation-settings-in-the-spyder-editor-for-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder uses spaces by default. However, that can be changed to tabs by going to

`Preferences > Editor > Advanced settings > Indentation characters`