# Spyder keyboard shortcut key

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

this might sound like really stupid question.

in pycharm when writing a line of codes i can simply press Tab to move the text cursor (or caret if you want to call it that) to the next position without inserting 4 spaces.

is there such a function in spyder. so i don't have to move my wrist almost 90 degrees every time to press the right arrow key?

i've searched all the shortcuts in spyder and don't seem find it.

thank you greatly!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187784/changing-indentation-settings-in-the-spyder-editor-for-python) help

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to use `\t` characters instead of spaces for your indentation? The question is not clear to me... the tab key is used for changing the indent level any time the cursor is within the leading whitespace of a line (tab increases indent, shift-tab decreases indent). This functionality is not treated as a special command, and cannot to my knowledge be re-assigned. there is an available shortcut however (which can easily be assigned to whatever) that advances the cursor to the next word...